# Can I wget or download files that are not linked to from a server?

Tags: wget, curl

I have a url such as `myurl.com/contents` and I am trying to fetch all contents in the folder.

Some files, such as `myurl.com/contents/unlisted-file.1` are not linked to anywhere. These files are otherwise accessible; if I `wget`them 
 explictly or type the address in the browser, I can see them.

Now, I am doing `wget myurl.com/contents -r -np` to fetch all the contents of the folder, but it is not downloading the unlisted files.

If my understanding is correct, this is by design - `wget` only downloads files that are linked to.

Is there any way to download **all** files - linked and unlinked - in a server folder, whether it's through `wget` or some other tool?

Comment: If opening `myurl.com/contents` lists all the files in that folder then only we can find a way to download them

Comment: You cannot access files that are not linked to and from which you don't know the complete path. This is intentionally by the design of http - if the _server_ don't create a directory listing (has to be configured to do so), the contents will be 'hidden'.

Comment: HTTP doesn't have any concept of directories, and doesn't provide a way to list all the files in a directory. So there's no way for `wget` to get the names of other files if they're not linked from somwhere.

Comment: You could use something like `scp` or `rsync`, assuming you have SSH access to the server.